# SPFX Application Customizer top navgation not opening in same tab

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I am using SPFX Application customizer for customized top menu bar.

It's working fine, except one issue. It's not opening in the same tab if using document library link with code `target="_self"`.

However, with page links it's opening in the same tab.

Is there a way to open the new page in same tab, no matter if the link is for document library or page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using document library link from same SharePoint site?

Comment: Yes ,From sharepoint online site